# ld: framework not found after pod install

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, podfile

I added Firebase libraries to my project, and then I got this error. When I compile it, Xcode can't find some directories. However, they are in the Pods directory.

Here is the error log:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Erumaru/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoTogether-gkzytezmbbgkikgoxjpptxgrixil/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Erumaru/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoTogether-gkzytezmbbgkikgoxjpptxgrixil/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: framework not found GTMSessionFetcher
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ToDoTogether' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  platform :ios, '10.0'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'  
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  # Pods for ToDoTogether

end
```

Comment: What is your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to show some effort or research to detail how you have tried to debug this. This will help narrow down the problem and create a more specific question. Right now, it seems that you have not made these debugging attempts or research, and just want someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: As a first step, try commenting out the Firebase pods, and see if you still get the GTMSessionFetcher error. The error is about GTMSessionFetcher, not Firebase. Start there maybe?

Comment: Likely the same issue and similar solution as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac

Comment: Make sure you're opening the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj file.

Comment: we're using GAE endpoints and the IOS API generator builds GTMSessionFetcher it into the generated code.....but GTMSessionFetcher also exists in Firebase and we're seeing a warning that this class is implemented both places and it's undefined which will be used.....in case that helps anyone

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Make sure you are opening the workspace file and not the project file. I was receiving the same error and realized I was using the project not the workspace.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same issue and I tried multiple things but still it was not working. I tried below.

1. Using XCworkspace file
2. Cleaned the project, restarted XCode, Mac
3. Turned bitcode to No
4. Deleted the search path for Framework, Library

Finally the thing that worked is, deleting pod file and re-creating pod file. It worked as magic!

P.S.: This is very generic error and so same solution may not work for all.

Answer (score 2):

Go To Project Target > Build Settings:

Look for Search Paths > **Framework Search Paths**, delete all paths which you have been warned; then in **Library Search Paths**, delete all paths which you have been warned.

Answer (score 2):

For me i had to change/edit the schema and choose the new one.

I had renamed my `debug` schema to `debug(development)` and that was causing my problem.

Fix:

1. `Product > Edit Schema > Change Build Configuration`

[image: Edit Schema]

What I did was create alternate `Configurations` and renamed my current one.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case I just had to go to **Edit Scheme** > **Run** and Reselect "None" as **Executable**.