# Xcode returns linker error "library not found for -lFirebaseAuth"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, linker

I wanted to test firebase initial app on Unity. I made a build from Unity in macOS and in Xcode project folder, I have runned the pod command successfully.

pod install

After this I opened Xcode project and I clicked to build button. Before this, I was getting framework not found error. I fixed it and now I am getting

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-giljorflztrrychfchrkhcfbqtbh/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-giljorflztrrychfchrkhcfbqtbh/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/aliavci/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-giljorflztrrychfchrkhcfbqtbh/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-giljorflztrrychfchrkhcfbqtbh/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-giljorflztrrychfchrkhcfbqtbh/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: library not found for -lFirebaseAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already added library pathes to library search path. I added some screenshots as attachments.

[image: xcode properties]

[image: podfile]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ld: framework not found after pod install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323326/ld-framework-not-found-after-pod-install)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I solved the error by opening ".xcworkspace" file, instead of ".xcodeproj" file.

Comment: Whenever you are using CocoaPods, you must always open the xcworkspace.

Comment: Important to set fastlane's gym to use workspace instead of project.