# ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, react-native-fcm

I using `react-native-fcm` for remote push notification but it gives this error:

ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Pod:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SefrTaSad' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SefrTaSad

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - Firebase (5.5.0):
    - Firebase/Core (= 5.5.0)
  - Firebase/Core (5.5.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.1.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (5.5.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 5.1.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (5.5.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (= 3.1.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (5.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.1)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.2)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 5.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 5.2)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 5.2)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (5.1.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 5.2)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (3.2.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 5.2)
  - FirebaseMessaging (3.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 5.2)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (5.1.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 5.2)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 5.2)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (5.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (5.2.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (5.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (5.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (5.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (5.2.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (5.2.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - nanopb (0.3.8):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.8)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.8)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.8)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.8)
  - Protobuf (3.6.1)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Firebase
  - Firebase/Messaging

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleUtilities
    - nanopb
    - Protobuf

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Firebase: 8c957f9cb3852b519180fb378801b7eeeba4d288
  FirebaseAnalytics: d4a260c114aec0d765ab5b9c404ac63de1d29381
  FirebaseCore: ee4b35cf8c8e781da296cc7c15125e4608bb954d
  FirebaseInstanceID: 8cd2c6cfe7b9ab65ce7e248f6da7f26f6775b9be
  FirebaseMessaging: f67b3719f520ee200da0e20ce577fe2bce0c01d0
  GoogleAppMeasurement: e785bdb86d3d280abc778156cec323a975f11d1d
  GoogleUtilities: 06b66f9567769a7958db20a92f0128b2843e49d5
  nanopb: 5601e6bca2dbf1ed831b519092ec110f66982ca3
  Protobuf: 1eb9700044745f00181c136ef21b8ff3ad5a0fd5

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 5128fcc348aba846d880d9bb9978b4bf02c0718d

COCOAPODS: 1.5.3
```

project build whit react-native
and I make appId, key and profile 
the app successfully conected to firebase console but when I want to archive it whit xcode it gives this error:

[image]

[image]

how can I solve this error ?

Comment: Try to check if the library has been included in the `Xcode -> Build Phases`, if not then manually add and rebuild

Comment: try also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021185/728287 - it worked for me as I forgot I ran `pod init`, which creates a `.xworkspace`

Comment: @PritishVaidya I'm facing the same issue, but I wasn't able to find the FirebaseCore.a at all. how can I manually add it, or do you mean something else?

Comment: You need to include xcodeproj file to the libraries first.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I resolved opening "PROJECT-NAME".xcworkspace

Comment: Unity3D created the XCodeProject with its dependencies, so I double clicked .xcodeproj file. Bad idea! As thodwris said: to also load the dependencias, we must open the `.xcworkspace` file!

Comment: This was true for me with a Cordova-created Xcode project.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `Build Active Architecture Only` setting in the `Build Settings` and make sure it's `Yes` for the `Debug`.

I was working on an old project and it was `No` for both `Debug` and `Release` for some reason and Xcode was trying to look for an arm64 version of Firebase for a simulator build.

Comment: For me it was actually the opposite. For me this was just a matter of removing the debug config from Project Navigator --> <project-name> --> Info --> Configurations (all this in XCODE). Go figure why...

Answer (score 2):

Add `libRNFirebase.a` to your `Linked Framework and Libraries`

Comment: how do you do that? I wasn't able to find libRNFirebase.a in the xcode project.

Comment: @JuneWang it seems Firebase is not linked to your Xcode project correctly. try to install it with cocopods. also you can follow the instructions in https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to link the APNs to Firebase. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

use in Podfile

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

after this go to terminal pod update

Comment: This is actually specifically contraindicated by https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

Answer (score 2):

In My case,

when command `pod install`,

pod install yellow warnings are showed

- Use the $(inherited) flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the targets.

---

So when xcode, project

Project => Build Settings => Library Search Paths

add  `$(inherited)` by non-recursive.

then problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all of your ios target versions are the same as in pod file.

Answer (score 0):

My case is different but maybe can help someone.

In my case, I had my application and I had a **Notification Service Extension**, which was the project that was getting the error.

I tried everything and nothing worked, I spend almost 4 hours trying to find a solution but with no success at all. So for no reason at all, I decided to check the iOS version defined for both, my project and the Notification Service Extention, and it was different, while my project was in version 11.0, the Extension was using 10.0.

So I put the Extension in 11.0 to match my project and voila, it worked.